# Setting a distance between two classes

Tags: html, css

Hey guys started learning HTML5 & CSS3 yesterday and just got stuck on something.
If any of you can help me out here, checked some other posts on here and tweaked the different margin options but I can't find the right rule.

I'm trying to space out a class called .content and another .byline (which are followed by eachother. 
I've tried:

Here's the CSS.

```
 .content {
  margin-bottom: 30px; }
```

Also:

```
.content.byline {
  margin: 30px 30px;}

.byline {
  margin-top: 30px;}
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="content">
  <h3> bla bla </h3>
 <span class="byline">blabla</span>
```

Here's both classes as of now:

```
.content {
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 40px;
 text-align: center;
 width: 70px; }

 .byline {
 font-size: 14px;
 padding-top: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 1Opx;
 font-family: Roboto;
 border-top: 2px solid #CCC;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #CCC; }`
```

Excuse my beginners explanation and thanks for helping me out here.

Comment: We need to see the HTML as well

Comment: If they are followed by each other then you need a space between `.banner` and `.byline` in the snippet above. Otherwise that's a selector for elements that have **both** classes... But yeah, please post HTML.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve??

Comment: `.content + .byline { margin-top: 10px; }`

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to answer man. It's not working though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`h3` elements have a margin on top and bottom by default. If you want your `byline` to gain more distance than this, by margin, you have to increase the `margin-bottom` of the h3 enough to make a difference.

Try adding `margin-bottom: 70px;` to your `h3`.

```
h3 {
    margin-bottom: 70px;
}
```

And by the way, your 10px in `padding-bottom` on the `.byline` is written with an "O".

Comment: Thanks Leon ! Is set the margin-bottom of the h3 to 1 px then added a margin to the .byline class with 0 75px; . Appreciate it man :)